# C++ Dynamic Array Increase Size By 1 with each add - ERROR

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I'm working on an assignment for an OO C++ class and I'm stumped. The assignment is to add grade (int) to a dynamic array and increase the size of that array by 1. The array must start with zero. Here are the specifications given to us:

Specification Bundle.

1. Specification B1 - Dynamic Array
   Create an array on the heap. Store student scores in it.
2. Specification B2 - Add Elements
   Start your array at size 0 and increase it by one every time you add
   a new score with menu option 1.

I've looked at numerous examples on the web in our book and I am just banging my head against the wall. I've moved stuff around, tried to put things in different orders etc. I've come up with the following code and it just wont work. I'm pretty sure someone with experience is just gonna tell me I forgot a comma but here goes. I understand the basic concept is to create the dynamic array, create a temporary array that is one size bigger, then copy the elements of the original array to the temp array and then to just point the dynamic array to the temp array's memory address, delete the old array then wash rinse repeat, but i just cant seem to do it. I need help :) Currently i get a heap corruption error message. Here's the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> // do not use
#include <ctime> // for seeding random numbers
#include <string> 

using namespace std;

//Global Variables

//Function Prototypes
void ProgramGreeting(); // All programs will have this method - Draw a happy litte tree
int mainMenu(int[], int*, int*); //Main Menu
void addGrade(int[], int*, int*); // Add a grade to the list. Takes the array  and the number of items in the array
void displayGrades(int[], int); // Display all the grades. Takes the array and the number of items in the array
void processGrades(int[], int); // Process all the grades. Takes the array and the number of items in the array
char letterGrade(int); // Return a letter grade
void Unittest(); // All CISP400 programs should have this.

int main()
{
    // Specification B1 - Dynamic Array
    int* grades = NULL;
    int max = 0;
    int numofGrades = 0; //A counter for the size of the dynamic array
    grades = new int[max];

    ProgramGreeting();
    mainMenu(grades, &numofGrades, &max);


    delete[] grades;

    return 0;
}

void ProgramGreeting()
{
    // Specification C1 - Program Greeting Function
    cout << "Welcome to GPA Analyzer!" << endl;
    cout << "Written by William Graves" << endl;
    cout << "This assignment is due on February 16, 2020" << endl;
}


int mainMenu(int grades[], int *numofGrades, int *max)
{
    char ans;

    do {

        cout << "Main Menu" << endl;
        cout << "--------------" << endl;
        cout << "1) Add Grade" << endl;
        cout << "2) Display All Grades" << endl;
        cout << "3) Process All Grades" << endl;
        cout << "4) Quit" << endl << endl;
        cout << "Enter your choice: ";
        cin >> ans;

        switch (ans) {
        case '1': //The user selected add grade
            addGrade(grades, numofGrades, max);
            break;
        case '2': //Display all grades
            displayGrades(grades, *numofGrades);
            break;
        case '3': //Display all grades
            processGrades(grades, *numofGrades);
            break;
        case '4': //The user chose to exit.
            cout << "Exit time. ";
            return 1000;
            break;
            // Specification C4 - Bulletproof Menu
        default:
            cout << "Your selection of '" << ans << "' is invalid. Try again." << endl;
            break;
        }
    } while (1);

}

void addGrade(int grades[], int *numofGrades, int *max) // Add a grade to the list. Takes the array  and the number of items in the array
{
    int gradeEntry = 0;
    cout << "Enter the grade: ";
    cin >> gradeEntry;
    if (gradeEntry <= 100 && gradeEntry >= 0) //verify that the grade entered is between 0 and 100
    {
        grades[*numofGrades] = gradeEntry;
        cout << "Grade of " << gradeEntry << " added successfully.";
        *numofGrades = *numofGrades + 1;
        if (*numofGrades >= *max)
        {
            *max += 1;
            //create a temporary array a size bigger:
            int* tempArray = new int[*max];
            //copy the contents of the old array to the newly allocated array
            for (int i = 0; i < *numofGrades; i++)
            {
                tempArray[i] = grades[i];
            }
            //get rid of the old array.
            delete[] grades;
            //change the memory location.
            grades = tempArray;
        }
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error occured. User entered: " << gradeEntry << " The grade must be an integer between 0 and 100. No grade added." << endl;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: One problem is that you're modifying local copies of `grades`.  Your changes do not passed back to the caller.

Comment: Is there a reason all this stuff is filled with pointers instead of using std::vector? also, `new int[0]` = ?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis - perhaps it is because they are working an a class assignment. I think the best place to discuss best practices is in an answer so you can fully flesh out your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

When debugging something like this, always try to walk yourself through the code line by line for a typical input. (Words of wisdom from my own Data Structures prof)

In this case it looks like it has to do with your array size.
You initialize an int array of size 0.
In your `first` call to `addGrade()` function, you
1. Get input from console. (so far so good)
2. Then you set `grades[0]` equal to your input
3. Then you resize the array.

The issue is the order of steps 2 and 3. You start with array of size 0, so you can't set `grades[0]` to anything because you haven't allocated memory for it yet. You must FIRST resize your array, THEN copy in your new (and old) data.

Hope that helps for this time around, but next time a bug comes around on an assignment, try to use it as a chance to test out some debugging techniques (no matter how primitive they may be). I'm sure your professor would gladly give suggestions on HOW TO DEBUG this.

Answer (score 0):

Your primary problem is you are passing *a pointer* to `grades` to your `addGrade` function:

```
void addGrade(int grades[], int *numofGrades, int *max)
```

(`int grades[]` is actually passed as `int *grades`)

When you do that `addGrade` receives a *copy of the pointer*, and since you are not returning the new pointer, nothing you do to `grades` in `addGrade` is ever seen back in the calling function. All changes are lost when the function returns.

You have two (really three) options (1) pass a *reference* to the pointer `grades`, or (2) change the return type of `addGrade` to `int *` and return a pointer to the new block of memory allocated and assign it to `grades` back in `main()`, and (3) - a note, you can pass the *address of* the pointer for `grades` to `addGrade` with `int**` as you would in C)

Here, preserving your `void` return type, the sensible thing to do is pass a reference to the pointer `grades`, e.g.

```
void addGrade (int*& grades, int *ngrades, int gradetoadd)
```

(with the general note that the really sensible thing to do is to use the STL provided `std::vector<int>` instead of the fundamental type `int*`, but I understand this is a learning exercise)

The next thing that will greatly help with debugging is to *Separate Your Implementation From Your User Interface*, meaning, don't co-mingle the user interface and the actual data processing logic of your code. Keep them separate. It makes coding *and testing* the implementation must easier. Then add the interface after your core data handling code is done.

For example, let's just write the `addGrade` function alone and a short interface that feeds it grades for testing. The only interface will be to send integers to `addGrade` for testing and a loop to spit out the results, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>

void addGrade (int*& grades, int *ngrades, int gradetoadd)
{
    int *newgrades = new int[*ngrades + 1];     /* allocate +1 integer */

    if (*ngrades) { /* if reallocating existing block of mem */
        memcpy (newgrades, grades, *ngrades * sizeof *grades);    /* copy */
        delete[] grades;       /* delete old */
    }
    grades = newgrades;        /* assign new block of mem to pointer */

    grades[(*ngrades)++] = gradetoadd;   /* add grade, increment ngrades */
}

int main (void) {

    int *grades = NULL,         /* a pointer to block of mem holding grades */
        ngrades = 0,            /* number of grades stored */
        tmp;                    /* temporary integer for input */

    while (std::cin >> tmp)                 /* while integer read */
        addGrade (grades, &ngrades, tmp);  /* add to grades, passing address of ptr */

    for (int i = 0; i < ngrades; i++)   /* output storged grades */
        std::cout << "grade[" << std::setw(2) << i << "] : " << grades[i] << '\n';

    delete[] grades;    /* free allocated block of memory */
}
```

Now any debugging is limited to the logic of the `gradeAdd` function itself uncluttered by menus, etc.. Above, `gradeAdd` now takes a reference to the pointer for `grades` and any changes to `grades` in `addGrade` are now made to the original `grades` from `main()` instead of a copy of the pointer. Compile and test:

**Example Input File**

File with 20 grades 50-100:

```
$ cat dat/grades.txt
74
61
67
75
73
86
95
54
93
99
68
100
95
84
50
58
79
86
98
80
```

**Example Use/Output**

Simple redirect the `dat/grades.txt` file as input on `stdin` to your test program:

```
$ ./bin/addgrade < dat/grades.txt
grade[ 0] : 74
grade[ 1] : 61
grade[ 2] : 67
grade[ 3] : 75
grade[ 4] : 73
grade[ 5] : 86
grade[ 6] : 95
grade[ 7] : 54
grade[ 8] : 93
grade[ 9] : 99
grade[10] : 68
grade[11] : 100
grade[12] : 95
grade[13] : 84
grade[14] : 50
grade[15] : 58
grade[16] : 79
grade[17] : 86
grade[18] : 98
grade[19] : 80
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/addgrade < dat/grades.txt
==4612== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4612== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4612== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4612== Command: ./bin/addgrade
==4612==
grade[ 0] : 74
grade[ 1] : 61
grade[ 2] : 67
grade[ 3] : 75
grade[ 4] : 73
grade[ 5] : 86
grade[ 6] : 95
grade[ 7] : 54
grade[ 8] : 93
grade[ 9] : 99
grade[10] : 68
grade[11] : 100
grade[12] : 95
grade[13] : 84
grade[14] : 50
grade[15] : 58
grade[16] : 79
grade[17] : 86
grade[18] : 98
grade[19] : 80
==4612==
==4612== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4612==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4612==   total heap usage: 23 allocs, 23 frees, 78,664 bytes allocated
==4612==
==4612== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4612==
==4612== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4612== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors. (All memory freed and no-errors is confirmation that you are using the memory you allocate correctly)

Now you `gradeAdd` function is read to be incorporated into the remainder of your code and you can have confidence that there are no problems with that function. Any further debugging is simplified. Look things over and let me know if you have questions.